# How to write testng testcase for private final anonymous class

Tags: junit, mockito, testng, final, private-methods

```java
private final SampleFormatter sampleFormatter = new SampleFormatter() {

    @Override
    public String formatDouble (int tag, double Value, int pre) { 
        if (Double.isNaN(Value)) {
            return "NaN";
        } 
        if (Value == 0.0D) {
            return "0";
        } else {
            return df.format(Value);
        }
    }

}
```

Here sample formatter is an interface and its method is implemented here.

How to get coverage for this format Double()  method by writing testng test case.

Comment: There is no private final method in the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry, Its not a private final method ,I have misunderstood that ,it is a private final anonymous class.

Comment: Either test through public methods that use this private field, or use a (package private) named class. If coverage is your goal, I would go with the latter. While getting access to this field via reflection is possible, it is far from elegant - your test will get mor complex than class under test.